# How to keep balanced and sorted binary tree

Tags: sorting, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have this binary tree which is supposed to be sorted, with each node having values from `[0,1]`, so `0.5` is a good root node to keep it balanced.

But as I sort, I get two long legs with no further branches..I know I have seen this before, but I dont remember how to do this right.

Like I said, the **problem** is it starts looking like a linked list instead of a tree and thats not what I want. Because I want to insert/delete in O(log(n)).

[image]

Comment: If you simply insert new values into the tree's existing structure, then its balance (or lack thereof) depends entirely on the order in which values are inserted.  If balance is important to you, then you will need to monitor the balance at every level of the tree, and actively rearrange the tree when things start to get lopsided.  *AVL trees* and *red-black trees* are two common implementations of this idea.

Comment: thanks that seems like a good answer, feel free to add that as answer..but as far as my original question, the drawing on the left is final, change it to the drawing on the right, is evidently not the right idea to keep a BST.

Comment: @jasonharper please comment on my answer, if you can specifics on how to implement AVL or red-black for this particular scenario that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement either an AVL tree orca red black trees, the algorithm will stay balanced with no need to add any seed nodes.  The guarantee on AVL trees is that no branch is more than one node longer than any other branch.  red black trees have a slightly less robust guarantee, but it is still good.

Comment: AVL is more balanced than Red/Black. My hypothesis is that seeding like I did in my answer, might help with Red/Black but might be redundant (or worse) with AVL..

Answer (score 1):

There are several structures and related algorithms that provide self-balancing trees -- or more generally -- sorted lists.

Among binary trees there are AVL trees and red-black trees. But in my own experience -- when having to deal with millions of values -- a B+tree has been an efficient option. It has some interesting features:

- easy to balance: no rotations, but splits and joins.
- memory is allocated in blocks -- ready for storing more than one value -- so that the *number* of allocations is much less than the number of stored values
- you can play with the branching factor to see which one gives best performance
- when the bottom layer is linked as a linked list, you have easy access to the ordered sequence of values

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AVL or Red/Black trees is answer to keep things balanced. Additionally, since I am building a BST for sorted values between [0,1], one option might be to start with a relatively complete tree? like so:

```
                 Node(0.875)
                /
            Node(0.75)
           /    \
          /      Node(0.625)
  RootNode(0.5)
          \      Node(0.375)
           \    /
            Node(0.25)
                \
                 Node(0.125)
```

and then adding nodes using that base tree, which will make everything cleaner, to expand even further:

```
                                / Node(0.9375)
                     Node(0.875)
                    /           \ Node(0.8125)
            Node(0.75)
           /        \           / Node(0.6875)
          /          Node(0.625)
         /                      \ Node(0.5625)
        /
  RootNode(0.5)                 / Node(0.4375)
          \          Node(0.375)       
           \        /           \ Node(0.3125)
            Node(0.25)
                    \           / Node(0.1875)
                     Node(0.125)
                                \ Node(0.625)
```

Using the above as a seed, will keep things relatively balanced, out of the gate.

Comment: This just looks like fooling the system, as now you have a tree with a lot of nodes which are artificial and do not represent actual data. That means the benefit of having a balanced tree is lost to the fact you now have to search along nodes which represent no real data, and so the amount of work of navigating the tree is still similar to navigating the unbalanced tree in your question -- their depths are the same.

Comment: @trincot I am trying to understand what the problem is? Yes these are dummy nodes, but it seems like a good way to seed, as the graph might not be easily balanced (in terms of computation or real data) in the first 1000-10000 cycles etc. What I am doing won't hurt tmk, but perhaps it won't help either.

Comment: It wont help -- that's my point. It's not so much different from having an unbalanced tree and then filling up the gaps with dummy nodes and then call it balanced. Do you know about AVL trees and black-red trees? They are the solution to the balancing problem.

Comment: yeah I learned abt `avl` and `redblack` from a comment on OP, I was going to use those in conjunction with this seed strategy, it will work, can't quite tell yet how good or bad it will be though.

Comment: @trincot from google "Red Black Trees provide faster insertion and removal operations than AVL trees as fewer rotations are done due to relatively relaxed balancing. AVL trees provide complex insertion and removal operations as more rotations are done due to relatively strict balancing"...so I assume if I use RBT, then my seed will help...perhaps with AVL, the seed will be redundant.

Comment: The time complexity of these self-balancing trees is the same. The gain one gets from performing fewer rotations will be countered by some longer paths to traverse. Performance wise I get better results with B+-tree, but again the time complexity remains the same. There is also skip list, and many many other options you can try. I personally have no belief in the *seed* idea: it just means you make the tree balanced by *adding* nodes, which obviously comes at a traversal cost. If you really benchmark all this, I'm sure you will drop that seed idea.

Comment: @trincot Think about a tree with million+ nodes. For big trees, with millions of values, with a uniform distribution from [0,1] (or any uniform), your best tree is going to have the type of values in this answer, and the way you would optimize the tree, would be different than a generic red/black etc, tmk. Red/black only considers optimizing for current nodes, really. We have more information, since we know the future distribution of the next million+ values.

Comment: I think B+tree is worth to look into. I used it with millions of numbers before, and I had better results than with the other data structures.

Comment: thanks I will check B+ tree out, sounds good

Comment: I haven't been thinking clearly recently and @trincot you were abs right, adding these dummy nodes will not help, only make things complicated and impossible lol. The only way it would work, is if you never really remove nodes and if the dummy values were meaningful, but anyway long story, not very useful, debating whether to just delete this answer -the only reason not to is that these comments have value. Maybe add an answer that includes a reference to B+ trees and then we can delete this answer.